# Sublime Snippet: use a * character in tabTrigger

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I need a tabTrigger that starts with a * character but it won't work. Already tried to escape it * but it doesn't work either. Ideas?

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
*CLOAD, KEYWORD1=${1:VALUE1}, KEYWORD2=${2:VALUE2}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>*CLOAD</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.abaqus</scope>
    <description>CLOAD Keyword</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Also tried to add this to the user settings file: {"selector": "text.abaqus", "characters": "*"} . No luck

Comment: Why not just use `CLOAD` as your trigger?

Comment: It works for me, have you tested it removing the scope?

Comment: @MattDMo True, why not just CLOAD as a trigger... the problem is that in that case if someone does types e.g. *CL and then TAB, the snippet won't be triggered...

Answer (score 0):

After reading sergioFC's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955544/sublime-snippet-use-a-character-in-tabtrigger/34005823#comment55688412_33955544), I tested the snippet in your question, and when I commented out the `<scope>` line, it worked fine. So, I suspect the issue isn't with the asterisk (`*` character), but with the scope. I had never heard of Abacus, and I still can't find a language syntax for Sublime or TextMate (although I did find an extremely minimal one for Atom, and keywords for NotePad++), but apparently its grammar is similar to Fortran. Correct me if I'm wrong.

At any rate, the language syntax you are using is most likely scoped as `source.abaqus` rather than `text.abacus`. `source` is used for source code, whereas `text` is used for things like Plain text, HTML, Markdown, LaTeX, etc. You can either leave the scope blank, at the risk of triggering your snippet(s) in other languages, or you can change it to `source.abaqus`. To find out for sure what the base scope is, you can use the following key combos to display the full scope at the cursor in the status bar at the bottom of the window:

- Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MattDMo. This didn't work though. I am developing the syntax for abaqus from scratch, since there is nothing available yet. I changed the scopeName at my tmLanguage file to source.abaqus, then I changed the scope in the snipped. No luck...  Abaqus is a Finite Element solver used in mechanical engineering. It takes an input file that is very similar indeed to fortran.

Comment: @SenhorLucas can you give me a link to your repo so I can check out the `tmLanguage` file? Also, could you add some example files so I can test them? I'm the maintainer of [Python Improved](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Improved), which I've been working on for a little over 2 years now, so I might be able to give you some pointers.